# Why do I get this null pointer exception?

Tags: java

So I'm getting this nullpointerexception. I know the line it's being caused at, I just am having trouble seeing what's causing it in my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NoDuplicatesQueueWilson<T> implements NoDuplicatesQueueInterfaceWilson<T>
{
private int MAX_QUEUE = 5; // Default array size, small for testing purposes
private T[] items; // The array of the queue.
private int front; // The first entered item of a queue.
private int back; // The last entered item of a queue.
private int count; // A counter.

public NoDuplicatesQueueWilson() // Default constructor
{
   T [] items = (T[]) new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
   front = 0;
   back = MAX_QUEUE-1;
   count = 0;
}

// Begin Queue Operations
// isEmpty() checks the array to determine if there is an items in it.
public boolean isEmpty()
{
  return count == 0;
}

// isFull() checks to see if the array is full or not.
public boolean isFull()
{
  return count == MAX_QUEUE;
}

// enqueue(Object newItem) adds items to the back of the queue if it is not full.
// If it is full, it will double the size of the array of items,
// and re-create the array, adding the item onto the new array.
public void enqueue(T newItem)   {
  if(!isFull())
  {
     back = (back+1) % (MAX_QUEUE);
     items[back] = newItem;
     ++count;
  }
  else 
  {
     MAX_QUEUE = MAX_QUEUE * 2;
     System.out.println("The array was full. We've doubled the size.");
     T [] items = (T[]) new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
     back = (back+1) % (MAX_QUEUE);
     items[back] = newItem;
     ++count;
  } // End if
} // End Enqueue
```

When I run it in my driver program (with test data), the exception occurs at line 43 of the given code (my main class containing the methods and constructors), which is in the middle of my enqueue method. Specifically this line:

```
items[back] = newItem;
```

Any suggestions on what I might need to do or be looking for to see where my mistake was?

Comment: can you explain   back = (back+1) % (MAX_QUEUE);? how u come up with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In constructor you are not initializing `T [] items` but you are creating new local variable. It should be

```
public NoDuplicatesQueueWilson() // Default constructor
{
   items = (T[]) new Object[MAX_QUEUE]; // notice the difference
   front = 0;
   back = MAX_QUEUE-1;
   count = 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Also please check `else` part of code in `enqueue` method.

Comment: Also, the same bug appears in the else leg of enqueue.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, this line assigns to a local variable, instead of an instance variable:

```
T [] items = (T[]) new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
```

You can access the instance variable `items` with `this.items`:

```
this.items = (T[]) new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
```

You could also just use `items = ...` as there is no ambiguity in this case.

The same bug is also in your `enqueue(T newItem)` method at `T [] items = ...`.